# Google Earth Engine: Get summary statistics of an image for the whole globe (not for a region)

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, spatial-statistics

Is it possible to get descriptive stats for an image for the entire globe? I've been trying to google this but I generally find two types of answers:

- Sats over a region using `image.reduceRegion(..)` or something similar; or
- Pixel level stats for an imageCollection, e.g. `image.mean()`.

Neither is what I'm looking for.

Here's a simple example. What if I want to get stats on the `image` variable? That is, what is the global temperature average for this date?

```
// 2m air temperature
var era5_2mt = ee.ImageCollection('ECMWF/ERA5/DAILY')
                   .select('mean_2m_air_temperature')
                   .filter(ee.Filter.date('2019-07-01'));


// Turn the image collection into a single image
var image = era5_2mt.mean();

// Calculate global average temperature for July 1st 2019
(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You created the image for july first, now you apply a reduceRegion to compute the overall average. Play around with scale to make sure the computation doesn't become to large:

```
// Calculate global average temperature for July 1st 2019
var globalMean = image.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry:testPol,
  scale: 10000,
  bestEffort: true
})
print(globalMean)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/12f0c9e7cc206976ae18f494de1a04da

Comment: Thank you for the answer! That indeed works fine, but it is a bit hacky having to define a geometry that mostly covers the entire surface of the planet. Is there really no built-in way of doing this?

Comment: I would say it is the opposite of hacky. as it give the flexibility to apply 1 function to any kind of geomtry. Imagine if you had to seperatly create functions that only would work on global scales, that would be hacky

Comment: I appreciate the flexibility of the `reduceRegion()` method, which I believe is what's useful in most cases. But if I want to get statistics for an entire image it is hacky to have to define a geometry and, yes, I would expect a separate function for it. If indeed it doesn't exist, I'm sure there are good reasons -- maybe too much computation and not useful in most cases -- but it would be a useful feature.